# protractor -errors Message:Expected 0 to equal 5

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

protractor show me error message
that there are no list item.

> conFusion App E2E Testing menu 0 item should show the number of comments 
>         Message:
>        Expected 0 to equal 5.
>         Stack:
>         Error: Failed expectation
>           at Object. (/Users/fullStock/anglerJs/conFusion/test/e2e/scenarios.js:37:23)

I did e2e test to ensure the number of comment list that will appear on page is 5.I used json server to serve up the data. I think the problem is element have not  appeared in the DOM yet.Is there any way to tell protractor to wait until an element finally appears in the DOM?

code e2e test

```
   describe('menu 0 item', function() {
beforeEach(function() {
  browser.get('index.html#/menu/0');
});

it('should have a name', function() {
      var name = element(by.binding('dish.name'));
      expect(name.getText()).
         toEqual('Uthapizza Hot $4.99');
});

it('should show the number of comments as', function() {
     expect(element.all(by.repeater('comment in dish.comments'))
        .count()).toEqual(5);

});
```

code html for comment

```
    <h4> Customer Comments &nbsp; 
                <span style="font-size:15px;">sorted by:<input type="text" ng-model="FiltText"></span></h4>
            <blockquote ng-repeat="commet in dish.comments |orderBy:FiltText">
              <h5>{{commet.rating}} Stars</h5>
                <h5>{{commet.comment}}</h5>
                <footer>{{commet.author}}, <span>{{commet.date|date}}.</span></footer>

            </blockquote>
```

protractor configuration

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
     specs: [
    'e2e/*.js'
      ], 
   capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },

 baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/',

  framework: 'jasmine',
   directConnect: true,

 jasmineNodeOpts: {
   defaultTimeoutInterval:30000
 }
};
```

Comment: Did you had a chance to check this manually?
And one more thing is your locator seems to be improved. Let me post answer for this with that particular locator. Kindly check and let me know

Comment: yes.I check this manually. Actually I type in terminal gulp watch to serve up this web application.comment list is there.every things right, but when I make protractor to do a test ,the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this updated test cases. The thing is, you haven't taken the whole repeater.

```
it('should show the number of comments as', function() {
     expect(element.all(by.repeater('commet in dish.comments |orderBy:FiltText'))
        .count()).toEqual(5);
});
```

Comment: I did it ,but did not salve the problem. the same problem occurs.